# Error (ymax not found) while adding a geom_line (different data) to a multi-layered ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a plot that summarizes a dataset by first plotting the median & quantiles in an area / black line, after which I want to outline a specific 'firm' with a red line.

I'd also like to do so while facetting on a variable, thus plotting multiple variables at once.

An example code of what I'd plot is as follows:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

dt <- structure(list(Firm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2008L, 
    2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 
    2009L, 2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2009L), variable = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("var1", "var2", "var3"
    ), class = "factor"), value = c(0.991894223, 2.216322113, 3.189415462, 
    0.663732077, 0.444826423, 2.674568191, 1.272077011, 7.691464914, 
    4.263339855, 0.214415839, 3.995328653, 6.028747322, 8.191459456, 
    0.16205906, 4.056495056, 5.17994524, 0.42435417, 0.678655669, 
    6.246411921, 0.505532339, 4.65045746, 8.85141854, 5.850616048, 
    2.028583225)), .Names = c("Firm", "Year", "variable", "value"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

head(dt)
   Firm Year variable     value
1     a 2008     var1 0.9918942
2     a 2009     var1 2.2163221
3     a 2008     var2 3.1894155
4     a 2009     var2 0.6637321
5     a 2008     var3 0.4448264
6     a 2009     var3 2.6745682
```

I now manually calculate the ymin, ymax, and y for the ribbon / line plots. They're plotting just fine.

```
dt_aggregates <- dt %>%
  group_by(variable, Year) %>%
  arrange(variable, Year) %>%
  summarize(y=median(value))
dt_aggregates$ymin <- 0.9*dt_aggregates$y
dt_aggregates$ymax <- 1.1*dt_aggregates$y
```

This will be the firm I want to highlight:

```
dt_focus <- filter(dt, Firm=="a")
```

The following plots just fine, and is almost what I want.

```
g <- ggplot(data=dt_aggregates, 
       aes(x=Year, 
           y=y,
           ymax=ymax,
           ymin=ymin,
           group=variable)) + 
  facet_grid(variable~., scales="free") + geom_line() + geom_ribbon(alpha=0.3) +
  theme_bw()
```

However, I want to add another line (for the one firm) onto this (in red). 
Once I try to add a new line with a separate dataframe, I get the following error. Any help on getting this to work is greatly appreciated

```
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ymax' not found
g + geom_line(data=dt_focus, 
            aes(x=Year, y=value, group=variable),
            col="red", size=2)
```

Comment: Plot "g" is based on dt_aggregates, which has the ymax and ymin values. Where as your dt_focus doesn't have these variables. You would need to add these to dt_focus to make the geom_line layer that you add work

Comment: you only have one value for each "firm" for each year? so I don't understand what line you're trying to draw?

Comment: I agree that the reproducible example isn't that representative of the final dataset, it reproduces the error though. I still can't get it to work even if I specify dt_focus$ymin <- dt_focus$value & when I do the same for ymax. How should I deal them, taking into account that I just want to draw a red line for the dt_focus dataframe?

Comment: your code doesn't reproduce dt the way you've presented it. Further you've mistake in changing the years in dt_focus (I fixed that in my console). And dt_focus has only 1 value for each variable and year combination, so what line are you trying to draw?

Comment: I stand corrected, I'm sorry. I changed the dataset; I just set ymin/ymax to be equal to df_focus$value and now it's plotting just fine. Thanks for the hint.